# Nucleophile attack on Epoxy rings

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

My professor had explained to us that a nucleophile always attacks on that carbon connected to an epoxy ring, which would make a stable carbocation, when the given compound with the epoxy ring is in an acidic solution(containing H+)

For example if this is the epoxy ring :[image]

The Nucleophile would attack on carbon A, as if A forms a carbocation, it is more stable than B forming a carbocation, if it is in acidic solution. If not in acidic solution the nucleophile attacks on the less hindered carbon(which is B).

But my book has a contradiction :[image]

In this reaction, C2H5- attacks on the less hindered carbon, not the carbon with more stable carbocation.

Is the book right. Also please explain are the above reactions(that my professor said) with epoxy rings always valid ?

Thanks.